# SQL subqueries or inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am building a new web application and have had a basic understanding of sql queries but I am stuck in this particular query.

These are the two tables I will be using this query. The "followingID" in the first table points to the "id" of the second table.

```
dbo.T_FOLLOWING_GROUP
-id
-groupLookupID
-followingID
-order

dbo.FOLLOWING
-id
-userID
-followingID
```

I need to get all the rows in dbo.FOLLOWING based on known values that I have of "userID" and "groupLookupID".

Is this enough information to go off of? I know there are ways of doing

```
`SELECT * FROM dbo.FOLLOWING 
 WHERE (insert select subquery here)`
```

Or is there some sort of `inner join` I need to use?

Comment: What part are you stuck on exactly?  This would fall under *basic understanding of sql*.

Comment: I am stuck on how to make this into one query. As of my current knowledge, I would separate into two different queries

Comment: If you "need to get all the rows in dbo.FOLLOWING based on known values that I have of "userID" and "groupLookupID".", what does dbo.T_FOLLOWING_GROUP have to do with this?

Comment: Your subject line mentions inner join, what do you think that means?  Also, what's with the backticks?  That's a MySQL thing and you tagged your question with sql-server.

Answer (score 1):

**INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT AnyTableName.AnyColumnName1, AnyTableName.AnyColumnName2, ..... --- out these two tables
    FROM dbo.T_FOLLOWING_GROUP INNER JOIN dbo.FOLLOWING
    ON dbo.T_FOLLOWING_GROUP.followingID = dbo.FOLLOWING.id
```

And then you can add WHERE Clause in the end to futher filter the result set

**IN Query**

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, ...........
FROM dbo.T_FOLLOWING_GROUP
WHERE followingID IN (
                        SELECT DISTINCT id FROM dbo.FOLLOWING
                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

To have all in one query (using joins) try this:

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM dbo.FOLLOWING f 
LEFT JOIN dbo.T_FOLLOWING_GROUP fg on (f.id=fg.followingID)
WHERE f.userID=xxx AND fg.groupLookupID=yyy
```

(use your known values in place of xxx and yyy).

Comment: Why are you suggesting an outer join?

Comment: What if we're looking for a particular row from FOLLOWING table which has no corresponding FOLLOWING_GROUP row? It is only a sample the question author have to play with (and tune it up to his own use case)